# Show loader while navigating to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, safari

I want to show loader/spinner while clicking on anchor tag for another page navigation

**Things I tried:**

```
1. 
window.addEventListener('pagehide', function (event) {
    $('.ajax-loader-container').show();
});

2. 
window.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function (e) {
    $('.ajax-loader-container').show()
});

3.
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
    var current_state = document.readyState
    if (current_state == 'interactive') {
        $('.ajax-loader-container').show()
    }  else if (current_state == 'complete') {
        $('.ajax-loader-container').hide()
    }
});
4.
$('.side-nav a').click(function() {
    $('.ajax-loader-container').show();
  });
```

**2&3** works but with a delay as the loader appears after loading the html

**4** works sometimes, sometimes not, reason is the **turbolinks** in rails.
I cant use `beforeunload` as it doesn't work in **Safari and iphone**

I am working on **RubyOnRails5.1**

Comment: You do realize this will only ever work if you're loading the pages with XHR requests? https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#displaying-progress